# Quickly adding single pin to MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I have a GPS coordinate (latitude, longitude) and I quickly want to place a single pin on a MKMapView showing that position. Everything works just fine, but as I only need a single pin with no callout is there a quicker way to do this or is what I have below what needs to be done?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"DETAILPIN_ID"];
    [pinView setAnimatesDrop:YES];
    [pinView setCanShowCallout:NO];
    return pinView;
}
```

NB: I don't need to check for reusable annotation views as I am only using the pin to show a  position in a detail view (which is destroyed and recreated the next time a detail view is requested).

Answer (score 125):

Instead of using the `-mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method, just put the code for an `MKPointAnnotation` into your `-viewDidLoad` method. It won't animate the drop, but it is very easy.

```
// Place a single pin
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[annotation setCoordinate:centerCoordinate];
[annotation setTitle:@"Title"]; //You can set the subtitle too
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Swift version:

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
let centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41, longitude:29)
annotation.coordinate = centerCoordinate
annotation.title = "Title"
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Comment: is it possible to animate the drop of an MKPointAnnotation?

Comment: You can't easily animate the drop. If you want the animation, use the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method.

Answer (score 38):

You can set the point and also the region like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);

MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1);
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[annotation setCoordinate:coord];

[self.staticMapView setRegion:region];
[self.staticMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Answer (score 9):

Simply you can add it like:

```
    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.0225,longitude: 72.5714)

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "Javed Multani"
    annotation.subtitle = "Surat, India"
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

It looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Swift version of add pin in MKMapView:

```
func addPin() {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    let centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 20.836864, longitude:-156.874269)
    annotation.coordinate = centerCoordinate
    annotation.title = "Lanai, Hawaii"
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Swift version of focusing a region or pin

```
func focusMapView() {
    let mapCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(20.836864, -156.874269)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapCenter, span)
    mapView.region = region
}
```

To learn more details visit "[Load MKMapView using Swift](http://webindream.com/load-mkmapkitview-using-swift/)".

Answer (score 6):

The easiest and simplest method to drop a pin and displaying Current Location in Map View is to simply add this code in your viewDidLoad method. (Assuming that user's current location is already fetched by you).

```
NSString *display_coordinates=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latitude is %f and Longitude is %f",coordinate.longitude,coordinate.latitude];

MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[annotation setCoordinate:coordinate];
[annotation setTitle:@"Click Labs"];            
[annotation setSubtitle:display_coordinates];
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to animate the drop, you will need to implement `viewForAnnotation` as you've done because that property is `NO` by default.

If you don't need to animate the drop, you could eliminate the `viewForAnnotation` method implementation completely and to disable the callout, set the annotation's `title` to nil or blank when adding the annotation instead.

If you do need the pin drop animation and you're also showing the user's location (blue dot), you'll also need to check for `MKUserLocation` in `viewForAnnotation` and return `nil`.

Otherwise, you could remove the whole `viewForAnnotation` method and the default red pin will appear without animation, the callout will show if `title` is not blank, and the user location will show as a blue dot.

Comment: Thats a good point, I did try not implementing viewForAnnotation but I did not realise that both my title and subtitle were pointing to NSStrings. I am not overly attached to the pin drop, but I think now its in a will leave it as it is. Thank you very much for your answer, very helpful and certainly something I will use in the future.